# Which ROS package is actually running in Turtlebot3?

Tags: turtlebot3

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello my friend,

As you may know, based on the Turtlebot3 documentation http://turtlebot3.robotis.com/en/latest/pc_software.html,  we need to install ROS into Turtlebot3. We also need to install ROS into the PC.  When running TB3, we need to run both.  Now my question is:

1. How do we know which ROS package is actually controlling TB3? For example,  Is the  gmapping in TB3 ROS running or is  the gmapping in PC ROS running?
2. How do we control this? If I want gmapping in PC ROS to run, how can I configure it?

Thank you.

--Kening

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/267146/which-ros-package-is-actually-running-in-turtlebot3?/) by [Kening Ren](https://answers.ros.org/users/29479/kening-ren/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-07-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The method to setup the tb3 involves setting up the PC as the master. This allows all topics to be accessed by both the TB3 and the PC.

1. In terms of what is running on what, the tutorial only has the bringup running on the tb3. The gmapping is run on the PC, but it takes in data through the tb3 bringup launch through the topics of scan and odom.
2. By cloning the tb3 repository on both the tb3 and your remote PC, you can run any of the launch files from either machine (except bringup which is on the tb3). If you launch on the tb3, it runs on the tb3; if you launch on your PC, it runs on the PC.

Hope this helps!!

---

Originally posted by [xnick77x](https://answers.ros.org/users/30994/xnick77x/) with karma: 77 on 2017-07-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0